# MongoDB Assertion Error

Tags: mongodb

I started seeing this in my mongodb production database logs

```
ns:my_app_production.artists query:{ $query: {}, $orderby: { semester: 1, name: 1 } }
Wed Jul 25 19:20:59 [conn199] Assertion: 10334:Invalid BSONObj spec size: -286331154 (EEEEEEEE) first element:_id: "agelio-batle" 
Wed Jul 25 19:20:59 [conn199] assertion 10334 Invalid BSONObj spec size: -286331154 (EEEEEEEE) first element:_id: "agelio-batle"
```

first i tried running a repair

```
mongo --repair
...
Wed Jul 25 22:20:39 [initandlisten] Assertion: 10334:Invalid BSONObj spec size: -286331154 (EEEEEEEE) first element:_id: "agelio-batle" 
0x467eaa 0x4183ca 0x62dd82 0x643478 0x532b22 0x64d196 0x6578b7 0x65ac31 0x65cd75 0x65d6d9 0x51a419 0x6195f5 0x61b0c5 0x61bd3d 0x4914c8 0x47ad9a 0x5e2e7c 0x5e60b9 0x5e78ad 0x6346a2 
 [0x467eaa]
 # several more what i assume memory addresses omitted
 [0x6346a2]
Wed Jul 25 22:20:39 [initandlisten] assertion 10334 Invalid BSONObj spec size: -286331154 (EEEEEEEE) first element:_id: "agelio-batle"  ns:my_app_production.artists query:{}
Wed Jul 25 22:20:39 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "Invalid BSONObj spec size: -286331154 (EEEEEEEE) first element:_id: "a...", code: 10334 }, terminating
Wed Jul 25 22:20:39  dbexit: 
...
```

i also tried running `db.repairDatabase();` from the mongo shell with the same results.

I have never seen this before.  Typically with mongodb a repair fixes most problems so im not sure how to proceed or troubleshoot this.  any ideas?

Comment: Whenever a document gets deleted, the size will be set to 0xEEEEEEEE. The index the query is using might not be updated correctly and is pointing to this deleted record. Repair should had fixed this, but can you try rebuilding the index? If this still doesn't help, would you mind creating a server ticket (https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa)? It would also tremendously help if you could provide the associated data files.

Comment: so after a dump/restore and several repair attempts, i was still having the same problem.  i was rather intimidated with the ticket filing so i left it pretty bare, but i uploaded all the files involved needed to address the issue (i hope) https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6617

Answer (score 1):

If an overall repair fails you can mongodump out the individual collections with a --repair option and attempt to isolate the issues.  You can even pass queries in to filter out the corrupt data from a corrupted collection, essentially working around the bad data, but it is an incremental and often slow process.  This is why it is always recommended to take backups and run in replica sets to avoid the scenarion where you are left with a potentially corrupt data set.

That said, if you have no way to restore from a backup or another replica set member, then you can try something like (with the database shut down):

```
mongodump --dbpath /path/to/source/data/files --repair --db <dbname> --out /path/to/repaired
```

If that does not work, then to skip the index read (which might be tripping you up):

```
mongodump --forceTableScan --dbpath /path/to/source/data/files --repair --db <dbname> --out /path/to/repaired
```

Thanks to Ren in the comments, the other thing you can try is dropping/rebuilding the index.  The table scan option (mongodump walks _id index by default) will avoid using the indexes for the dump.  So assuming you get the path and the database names right, the second option should work.

Comment: hmm... that just created an empty directory with my dbname.  `going to try and recover data from: artists` then straight to `dbexit`